# Retrofit with gson. How parse response?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

i use retrofit and gson in project. 
The answer comes from the server in the format

```
{
   1:"user1",
   2: "user2"
}
```

I have structure pojo

```
public class User {

@Expose
@Getter
@Setter
private int uid;
@Expose
@Getter
@Setter
private String nick;}
```

And request retrofit

```
@Get("/")   
User getPojousers();
```

But in response to dynamic key. How can I describe the class for response??

Comment: for starters, that would be a `List<User>`,  not simply a `User` that is returned

Comment: then you need a TypeAdapter for `List<User>`

Comment: @njzk2 `List<User>`? I don't think so. That Json is JsonObject not array.

Comment: @skywall: right, but as you can see the object contains several uids, each linked to a nick. Each key-value represents a different user, hence it can be seen as a list. (through a custom adapter, of course). In other languages, that would be called an associative *array*

Comment: @njzk2 Sure, multiple ids has similar meaning as list of users. I just can't agree with your opinion that he needs TypeAdapter for `List<User>` instead of `User`. I think it is confusing. He definitely needs TypeAdapter for `User`, but deserialize method may return list of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom adapter that will return a list of users for that object. (you'll probably need to fix the json so that it is valid, first)

```
@Override
public List<User> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> elem : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
        result.add(new User(Integer.parseInt(elem.getKey()), elem.getValue()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your `User` class needs a constructor with those 2 params, of course.

Comment: Can you post part of code, where TypeAdapter is registered and definition of class, where this method belongs?

Comment: This part of code I took from your answer. Your answer is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse `Users` class on your own (example with `SparseArray`):

```
public static class Users implements JsonDeserializer<User> {
    public SparseArray<String> values = new SparseArray<>();

    @Override
    public Users deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Users u = new Users();
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) json;

            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> elem : obj.entrySet()) {
                if (Util.isInteger(elem.getKey())) {
                    u.values.put(Integer.parseInt(elem.getKey()), elem.getValue().getAsString());
                }
            }
        }
        return u;
    }
}
```

To make this work add TypeAdapter to `Gson` instance:

```
private static GsonConverter getConverter() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Users.class, new Users());

    return new GsonConverter(builder.create());
}
```

And use this converter in `RestAdapter` instance:

```
mInstance = new RestAdapter
                .Builder()
                .setConverter(getConverter())
                .//
                .create(...)
```